# SQL Server 2012 SQLPs Module - Changing current location automatically?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I have a large library of existing powershell scripts, primarily to run some complicated logic and interactions between SQL Server and the file system.

The SQL interactions typically are performed through the cmdlet `Invoke-SQLCmd`.

Recently the SSMS version on all of my servers was upgraded to 2012.  This meant I had to make some changes to my code to remove references to the `sqlserverprovidersnapin100` and `sqlservercmdletsnapin100` since those are deprecated in 2012 in favor of importing the `SQLPs` module.

This has worked OK, but it seems that the `SQLPs` module is at some point changing the current location to `PS SQLSERVER>` instead of `<local folder>`, which makes a lot of my other commands fail.  For instance, if I run a `Test-Path` on a network drive, it works fine from the `<local folder>` location but will fail from the `SQLSERVER` location.

**Is this a known issue?  Is there a workaround or setting I can change for this?**

The main script I am worried about is over 1000 lines and has run with no issues for over two years until we made this change, so I'd like to avoid doing a line by line test of it if I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding a `cd <local folder>` as the first line of the script to break out of the provider. 
Feels hackish though.

Comment: You just add `cd <folder>` as the first line AFTER loading the provider?

Comment: Well I'll try it and let you know very shortly!

Comment: I put a `Set-Location` into my main procedure and it seems to have fixed it!

Comment: Thanks to @JorgeSandoval for explaining why. However I'm not buying that as 'not a defect', mainly because that is not my use-case. Thanks for confirming we are not crazy too.

Answer (score 26):

A little more information on WHY in sql 2012 it is changing to the SQLSERVER: directory...

When powershell imports sqlps module, the manifest defines a post script file named SqlPsPostScript.ps1. This file (first line) changes the current location to the SQLSERVER: provider

On x64 bit box the module is located - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS.

In powershell 3.0 automatic importing can make it difficult to tell when this will occur (in my experience).

Its not clear why (from a logical standpoint) it should do this. We don't want to touch the SQL server modules, so I guess you need to do an explicit set-location after import of the module. You might also look at this as a solution that's a little less hacky.

```posh
Push-Location
Import-Module sqlps
Pop-Location
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `Push-Location; Import-Module SQLPS; Pop-Location`

Comment: ps; to avoid the warnings described here: https://www.codykonior.com/2015/05/30/whats-wrong-with-sqlps/  redirect the warning stream then nullify it: `push-location; import-module sqlps 3>&1 | out-null; pop-location`

Comment: FYI - SQL 2016 SSMS SqlServer module fixes this issue and gets you on a track that will be updated much more frequently. Suggest migrating...

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by using the PSPath property (which contain Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::) of the file I was trying to copy, instead of the default property.
Hope it helps !