# copy-item in powershell sqlserver context failing

Tags: powershell

I have a complex script failing at a simple line.
What happens is I perform a

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "DB01" -Database "DATABASE" -BackupFile "F:\FILE.BAK"
Copy-Item -Path \\remotedb01\f$\file.bak -Destination F:\Backups
```

The error returned to me is
 Invalid Path: '\\remotedb01\f$\file.bak'

What I've found through testing is that it is failing because after the backup-sqldatabase command completes the working directory is

PS SQLSERVER:>
If I type c:
And then run the copy-item command again, it works normally.

I must be missing something painfully obvious but I'm not seeing it.
I'd rather not have a line in my powershell that just says C:, there must be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: copy filesystem::\\remotedb01\f$\file.bak F:\Backups

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it figure I find a solution right after I've given up and posted a cry for help?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/719ede23-9f1a-43f5-8c4e-8188fea0b19f/sql-server-2012-importmodule-sqlps-breaks-the-testpath-powershell-cmdlet?forum=sqlsmoanddmo

Solution 1:

```
Test-Path -path "\\server\directoryname"
Import-Module 'sqlps' –DisableNameChecking
test-path -path  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\directoryname
```

Solution 2:

```
Test-Path -path "\\server\directoryname"
Import-Module 'sqlps' –DisableNameChecking
C:
Test-Path -path "\\server\directoryname"
```

Just replace Test-Path with Copy-Item and Import-Module with Backup-SQLDatabase and the solution is a match.

Considering solution 1 means adding a dozen additional characters, I'm going with a plain C: as the fix.

Comment: It looks like this question covers the same thing, and they came to the same conclusion - a CD back to the FileSystem provider is probably the best answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915299/sql-server-2012-sqlps-module-changing-current-location-automatically